# How to test if other models were created correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Account.create! method that creates multiple other models.

In my RSpec test how can I test if the other models were created correctly?

```
it "should create an account" do
  params = ....
  Account.create!(params)
  expect(account.valid?).to eq(true)
end
```

My Account.create! method looks like:

```
def self.create!(params)
   account = Account.new(params)
   user = ...
   user.save!
   location = ...
   location.save!

   account
end
```

Comment: This seems far from the best practices. Firstly, you should not override `create!` function and use `after_create` hook instead. Apart from that - is this user and location in any way associated with this account? If no, then this might not even belong to model at all and should be moved to the controller. If yes, you can easily test those objects are created with `account = Account.create!; expect(account.user).to be present`.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you can test that the records were created at all.

```
it "should create a user" do
  params = ....
  expect(Account.create!(params)).to change{User.count}.by(1)
end
```

Also, you can use `User.last` to retrieve the last user created and check the attributes are what you would want to see.

Comment: actually maybe I should have Account.create! return an object that has all the other objects?

Comment: That would be changing the intent of your method, no?  But yes, are `user` and `location` both associated with `account`?
Then you could do `new_account = Account.create!(params)` and then you can test `new_account.user` and `new_account.location`